# IEnumerable of Generics Type Parameters <Tx>?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to improve code of the following structure:

```
foreach (var operation in operations)
{
    if (IsTypeAndDoSomething<Type1>(operation))
    {
        Run((Type1)operation);
    }
    else if (IsTypeAndDoSomething<Type2>(operation))
    {
        Run((Type2)operation);
    }
etc.
```

I would prefer to avoid a long list of `else if` blocks with essentially the same pattern throughout.

In this project, we create an overloaded Run method to perform each operation.  When an operations list is running, we need to first identify the type of each operation and then prepare it (the DoSomething part), before running it with `Run`. Currently, repeated else if approach seems necessary.

However, I am wondering if there is any way in C# that the code above code is made more "generic" without the repeated `else if`s.

One idea was to create a collection of types, e.g.

I was wondering if there is any way to iterate a list of types to generic type parameters?

```
var types = new[] {typeof(Type1), typeof(Type1)};
```

Then when we add a new operation implementation we can simply add it to that collection (instead of multiple `else if` blocks we'd have another iterator).

However, we would need to somehow pass each item as Tx:

```
IsTypeAndDoSomething<Tx>
```

It does not seem possible to reference those types within a generic type parameter (T).  I assume that this is because it is done at compile-time rather than run-time.

Is this possible or is there a different pattern recommended?

Comment: [Pattern matching?](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

Comment: Do you have control over `Type1`, `Type2` etc? Can you add methods to them, and make them implement a common interface? If so, you should make use of polymorphism.

Comment: Why not using polymorphism? https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism maybe coupled with dynamic programming or reflection.

Comment: What does `IsTypeAndDoSomething` do exactly?

Comment: To elaborate on Cid's comment - [Pattern matching using switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements)

Comment: Why not using polymorphism?  In this case our object model is automatically generated from an XSD document (using XSD.EXE) so it is not easy to use polymorphism.

Comment: What does IsTypeAndDoSomething do exactly?  I've removed unnecessary complexity from the example code.  Basically if the type matches then it does something internal using type (via refelection).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just writing out the question helped me to see the answer is to a convert to a non-generic method, i.e.

```
 private bool IsTypeAndDoSomething(Type type, object operation)
```

With this change, type is handled at run-time and it is therefore possible to replace repeated matching else if blocks with the following:

```
            var types = new[] {   
                                        typeof(Type1),
                                        typeof(Type2)
                                    };

            foreach (var operation in operations)
            {
                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    if (IsTypeAndDoSomething(type, operation))
                    {
                        Run(operations, (dynamic) operation);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This seems worse than the original. Generic is always preferable to a System.Type object when you have a value

Comment: The original requirement here is to avoid a long else if block with repeated else ifs (each only differing by type).  I can't think of a generic way to do this (as the type is only known at run-time) but I welcome any thoughts.  I've updated my example code above to show the fuller solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to pattern matching could be to use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

You introduce a visitor interface

```
interface IOperationsVisitor<T> {
    T Visit(Type1 obj);
    T Visit(Type2 obj);
}
```

And add an Accept method to the base class for your operations:

```
T Accept(IOperationsVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
```

Then you simply implement the visitor interface and call the `Accept` method on your object, with the visitor object as the parameter.

This is much more cumbersome than pattern matching, but an advantage is that if you introduce a new type you will be forced to update all the visitors to handle the new type. With pattern matching it can be easy to forget to all the places the type is checked.